# Is an Android Service a process or thread?

Tags: android, service

Is an Android "Service" considered a process or a thread according to operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Service can be implemented as a separate process depending on the requirement. 
[Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg19511.html) is a good explanation when to implement the service as a separate process or as a component inside an existing app (Service with Activities in same process).

Answer (score 12):

It is neither, any more than an activity is "a process or a thread".

All components of an Android application run inside a process and by default utilize one main application thread. You can create your own threads as needed.

Comment: If it's not a separate proccess, why to comunicate between activity to bound service we must use AIDL or Messager?

Comment: @MarcinMierzejewski: You do not have to use AIDL or a `Messenger` to communicate with a bound service. Only if that service is in another process do you have to use IPC-based mechanisms, like AIDL.

Comment: Ok so using IPC for that in most cases is a overkill?

Comment: @MarcinMierzejewski: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Service is not a process nor a thread. Its a part of the process and a main thread. Like all other components - service runs in the main thread.. Lets say - your application has an Activity and a Service then your Application is a unix process which has a process id (pid) and runs in a instance of DVM... Process spawns a first thread which is main thread.. All your application components runs in main thread by default - you can call separate thread to do parallel jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, processes host services in the Android OS, so it's not a process. Maybe have a look at the definition of a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for more details...